# DirectX: Get InfoQueue before Device

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11, dxgi

Is there a way to get the InfoQueue or set the break parameters before the Device is created?

Right now i am creating the Device and then getting the InfoQueue, but any messages that are emitted before that point are going to be ignored and buried in the output window.

```
ID3D11Device* pDevice;
//...Create Device...
ID3D11InfoQueue* pInfoQueue;
pDevice->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID3D11InfoQueue), &pInfoQueue);
pInfoQueue->SetBreakOnSeverity(D3D11_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_ERROR, TRUE);
```

And I want something like:

```
ID3D11InfoQueue* pInfoQueue;
//...Get InfoQueue...
pInfoQueue->SetBreakOnSeverity(D3D11_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_ERROR, TRUE);
ID3D11Device* pDevice;
//...Create Device...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is enable DXGI debugging which will provide debug information for the device & swapchain creation.

```
#include <dxgidebug.h>


#if defined(_DEBUG)
    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IDXGIInfoQueue> dxgiInfoQueue;

    typedef HRESULT (WINAPI * LPDXGIGETDEBUGINTERFACE)(REFIID, void ** );

    HMODULE dxgidebug = LoadLibraryEx( L"dxgidebug.dll", nullptr, LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32 );
    if ( dxgidebug )
    {
        auto dxgiGetDebugInterface = reinterpret_cast<LPDXGIGETDEBUGINTERFACE>(
            reinterpret_cast<void*>( GetProcAddress( dxgidebug, "DXGIGetDebugInterface" ) ) );

        if ( SUCCEEDED( dxgiGetDebugInterface( IID_PPV_ARGS( dxgiInfoQueue.GetAddressOf() ) ) ) )
        {
            dxgiInfoQueue->SetBreakOnSeverity( DXGI_DEBUG_ALL, DXGI_INFO_QUEUE_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_ERROR, true );
            dxgiInfoQueue->SetBreakOnSeverity( DXGI_DEBUG_ALL, DXGI_INFO_QUEUE_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_CORRUPTION, true );
        }
    }
#endif
```

See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/dxgi-debug-device/) and [this one](https://walbourn.github.io/anatomy-of-direct3d-11-create-device/)

Answer (score 2):

Given the documentation for ID3D11InfoQueue saying that you get the interface pointer via a QueryInterface call on the device I would say the answer is 'no'.